# JavaScript object doesn't mutate

Tags: javascript

I would like to transform property of my object: `lists_to_download: { 10920: "10920" }` to `lists_to_download: ["10920"]`, so I've created a processor class, which handles this type of operation, but it doesn't mutate my input object and I don't know, where's the problem. Take a look at the code bellow and see the `console.log` outputs there.

```
class ObjectKeysToArraySettingsProcessor {

  constructor(objectPath = []) {
    this.objectPath = objectPath
  }

  _preProcessRecursion(part, objectPathIndex) {
    if(_isArray(part) && objectPathIndex < this.objectPath.length - 1) {
      part.forEach(item => {
        this._preProcessRecursion(item, objectPathIndex + 1)
      })
    } else if(objectPathIndex === this.objectPath.length - 1) {
      if(_isEmpty(part)) {
        part = []
      } else {
        console.log(part) // it prints { 10920: "10920" }
        part = _map(part, id => id)
        console.log(part) // it prints ["10920"]
      }
    } else {
      this._preProcessRecursion(
        part[this.objectPath[objectPathIndex + 1]],
        objectPathIndex + 1
      )
    }
  }

  preProcessSettings(settings) {
    if(!_isEmpty(this.objectPath)) {
      try {
        this._preProcessRecursion(
          settings[this.objectPath[0]],
          0
        )
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        return settings
      }
    }
    console.log(settings) // but here it prints lists_to_downloads: { 10920: "10920" } again...
    return settings
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably `_map(part, id => id)` creates a new array and you are assigning it to a local variable `path`.
But the reference to the old value of `path` is kept in `settings` object.
In order to do what do you want you have to pass `settings` to the function and change the value in settings object.

Comment: @RidgeA I can't pass `settings` to the function, I have to do it recursively, because object path can be fex. `['parameters', 'films', 'additional' 'lists_to_downloads']`, where 'films' could be an array. Also I taught that objects are passed by reference.

Comment: But you anyway can't do it in the way you want to. JS doesn't work like this. You have either to pass an object that will hold a property with reference to another object  or return a new value from the function and reassign it outside (in `preProcessSettings` function according to your example)

Comment: @RidgeA thx, I'll probably know, what you mean.

Comment: const newKeys = Object.keys(data).map( key => data[key])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to do the transformation in previous / not last step of the recursion

```
_preProcessRecursion(part, objectPathIndex) {
    if(_isArray(part) && objectPathIndex < this.objectPath.length - 1) {
      part.forEach(item => {
        this._preProcessRecursion(item, objectPathIndex + 1)
      })
    } else if(objectPathIndex === this.objectPath.length - 2) {
      const attribute = this.objectPath[objectPathIndex + 1]
      if(_isEmpty(part[attribute])) {
        part[attribute] = []
        return
      } else {
        part[attribute] = _map(
          part[attribute], id => id
        )
      }
    } else {
      this._preProcessRecursion(
        part[this.objectPath[objectPathIndex + 1]],
        objectPathIndex + 1
      )
    }
  }
```